# Flowable<List<T>> changes to empty List on Fragment switching back

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, android-livedata

I'm trying to populate a `RecyclerView` by following the nexts steps:

1. Download data from server and getting a `SoapObject` (yah, old server)
2. Transform the data to `Flowable<List<MyItem>>` (in Repository) in order to subscribe to it (in `ViewModel`) through `LiveDataStreams.fromPublisher(flowableObj)`
3. Set the resulted list into a MediatorLiveData object.
4. Observe the MediatorLiveData object in the `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated` method.

So, when I click an on item from the list, it navigates (through `Navigation Component`) to a new Fragment, but, once I go back through the phone's back button, the list becomes empty and consequently the observer is notified and updates the list (shows nothing cause is empty).

I don't know why, the list gets empty and therefore the RecyclerView. Any help? -- code below:

**Generic Fragment**

```
public abstract class ListFragment<T> extends Fragment {

protected ListViewModel mViewModel;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(getDataBindingObject().getRoot());

    showItemsList();
    setUpFilters();
}

protected void showItemsList() {
    mViewModel.getList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), listObserver);
    mViewModel.getItemSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), onListItemSelected());
}

protected final Observer<List<T>> listObserver = new Observer<List<T>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<T> list) {
        mViewModel.setListAdapter(list);
    }
};
```

**MyItem Fragment's code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelFactory()).get(MyItemViewModel.class);

    mDataBinding = ...
    mDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this); //geViewLifecycleOwner()
    mDataBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);

    return mDataBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mNavController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    
}
```

**Generic ViewModel:**

```
public abstract class ListViewModel<T, K> extends MyViewModel {

protected ListRepository<T> mRepository;
protected MediatorLiveData<List<T>> list;
protected MutableLiveData<K> mListAdapter;

public ListViewModel() {
    super();
}

public LiveData<List<T>> getList() {
    if (list == null) {
        LiveData<List<T>> lD = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(mRepository.getList());
        list = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        list.addSource(lD, li -> {
            this.list.postValue(li);
            list.remove(lD); //removing this line does not work either
        });
    }
    return list;
}

public LiveData<K> getListAdapter() {
    if (mListAdapter == null)
        mListAdapter = new MutableLiveData<>();
    return mListAdapter;
}

public abstract void setListAdapter(List<T> list);
```

MyItemViewModel:

```
public class MyItemViewModel extends ListViewModel<MyItem, MyItemAdapter> {

protected MyItemRepository mHistoryRepository;

public MyItemViewModel(MyItemRepository repository) {
    super();
    mRepository = repository;
}

@Override
public void setListAdapter(List<MyItem> list) {
    if (getListAdapter().getValue() == null) {
        MyItemAdapter adapter = new MyItemAdapter(list);
        adapter.setListener(onListItemSelectedListener);
        mListAdapter.setValue(adapter);

    } else
        mListAdapter.getValue().updateList(list);
}
```

**Generic Repository**

```
public abstract class ListRepository<T> {

protected Flowable<List<T>> list;

protected abstract Flowable<List<T>> getItemsList(int orderByField);

public Flowable<List<T>> getList() {
    if (list == null)
        list = getItemsList();
    return list;
}
```

**MyItemRepository**:

```
public class MyItemRepository extends ListRepository<MyItem> {

protected static volatile MyItemRepository instance;
protected final MyItemLocalDS mLocalDataSource;
protected final MyItemRemoteDS mRemoteDataSource;

public MyItemRepository(MyItemRemoteDS remoteDataSource,
                                      MyItemLocalDS localDataSource) {
    this.mRemoteDataSource = remoteDataSource;
    this.mLocalDataSource = localDataSource;
}


public static MyItemRepository getInstance(MyRemoteDS remoteDataSource,
                                                         MyLocalDS localDataSource) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new MyItemRepository(remoteDataSource, localDataSource);

    return instance;
}

@Override
protected Flowable<List<MyItem>> getItemsList() {

    list = mRemoteDataSource.download(...)
            .map(soapObject -> parseItemsList(soapObject))
            .map(wsResult -> transformItemsList(wsResult));

    return list.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: This is happening because when you are coming back to previous fragment you are getting a callback to your observer with empty list which is causing empty list. You may need to use single event live data where you will get callback in fragment only once. Refer https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70 for more information.

Comment: so, you say instead of the MediatorLiveData for the 'list' object, I should use SingleLiveEvent?

Comment: No, try changing this MutableLiveData --> SingleEventLiveData only.

Comment: the MutableLiveData regarding the Adapter? But, in this case, even the adapter does not change because the singleLiveData obj just notify once, the Mediator object (the one regarding the list) will be updated 0 elements

Comment: can you create a sample app with the same code and share github link. I will try to fix your issue and get it reviewed.

Comment: your approach was correct, actually it worked, the other question was just about detailing. Thank you!

Comment: nice to know that you have fixed that issue by following my approach. ;-)